# Prevent keyboard from popping up when clicking a text box on Android

Tags: samsung, keyboard, 8.1-oreo, external-keyboard

We have a Samsung Galaxy tablet running Android 8.1. We use it for inventory. We have a Bluetooth scan gun that goes with it and when hooked up to a tablet it registers as a physical keyboard. It works just fine. The problem is on the website (sage inventory tracker) we use, it has text boxes. You click the text box and scan the barcode and it fills in the information. This works just fine, but the keyboard pops up every time you click the text box which is annoying to the people using it.

I can turn off the show on-screen keyboard so it doesn't come up, but there are times when you need the on-screen keyboard to type things in, so you have to go back to the settings and turn it back on to get that to work.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a shortcut to either turn show on-screen keyboard on and off without needing to go to the settings every time or a way to just manually turn on the on-screen keyboard with a button click or from the drop-down notification bar. I've tried many different things but can't find a way to get it to work.

Comment: Use [Termux Widget](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Widget) to create a screen widget which calls the shell command `am start -a android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS`.

Comment: is there a way to do something like am start -a android.settings.HARD_KEYBOARD_SETTINGS.SHOW_ON-SCREEN_KEYBOARD=FALSE. or true. What would be better to create a toggle. So if on goes to off. and if off go to on.

Comment: No AFAIK. You need to open both screens one-by-one and make changes. So you can create two shortcuts on home screen; one with `am start -a android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` and the other with `am start -a android.settings.HARD_KEYBOARD_SETTINGS`.